# How to change heading style numbering format in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I see style numbering is not reflected in numbering setup window. Is this a bug? How to change numbering?

[image]

Comment: You have to click `OK` for the changes to take affect.

Comment: I didn't change anything

Comment: You need to change the numbering to what you want. If you don't see the format you want, use the `Define New Number Format...` button to define your own. Or use the numbering menu in the paragraph menu.

Comment: I want to fine tune current format, not create new format from scratch.

Comment: IMO, if you use the numbering menu from the paragraph section (rather than styles) of the ribbon you will have more options to adjust the numbering.

Comment: But I want to change the style, not to change the numbering of one specific paragraph.

Comment: That is not what you asked. You really need to read [ask] to help you ask complete questions.

Comment: I mentioned 'heading'. This is the style name. So, I want to change style. Anyway, I fixed the title to emphasize this point.

Answer (score 4):

If you are changing any of the characteristics of a multilevel list (which you probably are, in this case), don't go through the Style->Format->Numbering dialog. Go through the Multilevel list dialog on the Home tab of the Ribbon.

Personally, I still find this entire process exasperating so cannot really offer much more help than that, but you may find the late [Shauna Kelly's page on the subject](http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) useful